# DSLR suddenly switches from RAW to FINE

Tags: nikon, dslr, file-format, nikon-d3400

I've noticed that sometimes my Nikon D3400 suddenly "decides" to switch from RAW to FINE (most of the times it happens when I take the SD card out, but I don't really understand why). Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?
Honestly it's a bit annoying having to check every time that the file format is the right one.

My camera is in manual mode 99% of the times, but I have just set RAW and made a slow switch to every mode and the format didn't change, so I don't think that the problem is scene or automatic modes defaulting to FINE.

Comment: None of my different Canon cameras has ever switched itself out of RAW, in years, in any mode. I know that many cameras don't allow HDR and/or Wifi usage together with RAW (not that those functions would be related in any way).

Comment: Doesn it happen the moment you take the card out or when you put it back in? If the latter, maybe there is a quick speed test and the camera thinks wrongly that the card is too slow to support RAW. Also, does it happen with any card or just with one?

Comment: @Aganju I just checked my cameras. You're right! I guess that tells us how long it has been since I've used a "full auto" mode with any camera.

Comment: "most of the times it happens when I take the SD card out" - ok, so, a few more questions to consider (in addition to @xenoid's comment): Do you switch off the camera to remove the SD card or do you eject it whilst the camera is switched on? Is the camera _ever_ switched on without any SD card in it? Do you delete photos from the card using an external device (e.g. computer) prior to putting the card back into the camera, or do you only delete/reformat the card in the camera?

Comment: To answer to xenoid and @Kat, I don't know, because I always eject after turning the camera off. Sometimes I forget that the card isn't in and turn the camera on, then I insert the SD and I notice that it is set on "FINE". I usually empty the card using my PC and I've only formatted it the first time I used it. Aganju my camera does not support neither Wifi nor HDR, so that should not be the problem

Comment: @Kiro Thanks for clarifying. I did wonder if it might be the camera detecting no SD card present, but having tried in my Nikon (different model) it retains the RAW setting after a card is inserted. Your method of switching the camera off before ejecting is the recommended one, too, so I think we can rule that out as a cause as well. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what else that leaves to investigate.